# Acquiring AD OU list

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I am looking to be able to pull a list of current OU's from Active Directory I have been looking at some example code online for sometime, but O don't seem to be able to get this to work.

```
        string defaultNamingContext;

        DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE");
        defaultNamingContext = rootDSE.Properties["defaultNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
        DirectorySearcher ouSearch = new DirectorySearcher(rootDSE, "(objectClass=organizationalUnit)", 
            null, SearchScope.Subtree);

        MessageBox.Show(rootDSE.ToString());
        try
        {
            SearchResultCollection collectedResult = ouSearch.FindAll();
            foreach (SearchResult temp in collectedResult)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(temp.Properties["name"][0]);
                DirectoryEntry ou = temp.GetDirectoryEntry();
            }
```

The error I get is There provider does not support searching and cannot search LDAP://RootDSE       Any Ideas?
for each of those returned search results I want to add them to a combo box. (shouldn't be too hard)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot search on the `LDAP://RootDSE` level - that's just an "informational" address with some stuff. It doesn't really represent any location in your directory. You need to bind  to the default naming context first:

```
string defaultNamingContext;

DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE");
defaultNamingContext = rootDSE.Properties["defaultNamingContext"].Value.ToString();

DirectoryEntry default = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + defaultNamingContext);

DirectorySearcher ouSearch = new DirectorySearcher(default, 
                                     "(objectClass=organizationalUnit)", 
                                     null, SearchScope.Subtree);
```

Once you do that, you should be OK to find all OU's in your domain.

And in order to speed things up, I would recommend not searching using `objectClass` - that property is *not* indexed in AD. Use `objectCategory` instead, which is indexed:

```
DirectorySearcher ouSearch = new DirectorySearcher(default, 
                                     "(objectCategory=Organizational-Unit)", 
                                     null, SearchScope.Subtree);
```

**UPDATE:**
I discovered this filter is wrong - even though the `objectCategory` is shown as `CN=Organizational-Unit,.....` in the [ADSI browser](http://adsi.mvps.org/adsi/Delphi/adsibrowser.html), you need to specify `objectCategory=organizationalUnit` in the search for it to succeed:

```
DirectorySearcher ouSearch = new DirectorySearcher(default, 
                                     "(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)", 
                                     null, SearchScope.Subtree);
```

Comment: I have tried to search using your suggestion above, its seems a really good idea, though it has a noob trying to implement it. I changed default to 'domain', which i couldn't see there being a problem doing, my issue is that domain = System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry, rather than LDAP://... though that is in its Path property.

Comment: Just thought I'd add for anyone who finds this later. Server 2003 R2 and earlier did *not* index `objectClass`, however 2008 and later do. Not a knock against the answer! Just new information. Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675095(v=vs.85).aspx