# Get OU list from active directory using c# with hierarchy

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, active-directory, c#-3.0

I want to retrieve OU structure from active directory using c# into a treeview
So far I found [Acquiring AD OU list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903541/acquiring-ad-ou-list) 
I have tested, it worked fine,this is good to get a flat list of all OUs without any hierarchies.

How could I get hierarchical list with the extent of above method ? I am using .net 2.0 and VS 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved it by add one level each time and wait for user's action to loop through next level which can split query into multiple small queries which take much less time for each run.

Comment: Nice one, gonna try it out. Would you have come across any other solution by any chance ? (just curious :) )